# How to display search results on ajax search?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a ajax autocomplete search and display the results. I develop small search box with autocomplete but i am struggling with showing search results , can anyone guide me ?

```
search.php 
=========
<script>
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $last_name = $clicked.find('.last_name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($last_name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

here the index file which i have done so far ...........

```
index.php
=========

if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['search'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("select personal_names_id,last_name,initials from personal_names where last_name like '%$q%'  order by personal_names_id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$last_name=$row['last_name'];
```

what i want to do i display the results which related to auto-complete text data ?

Comment: So umm what's not working? Are you getting back data from the AJAX? Your `index.php` is incomplete by the way.

Comment: yes im getiing the data to dropdown , what i want is to display the results according to selected values

Comment: Is anything being displayed in your `#result`? If not, please paste the full code of `index.php` and try running the same query in your phpmyadmin to see if you get any results

Comment: trigger an event on "$('#id').change(get results here and display) or .blur()"